# First creation of file in objective c project

Tags: sql, objective-c, plist

i'm developing one of my first app in iphone and i have a little doubt: where should i verify existence of my database and plist files in Document folder?

I use these data in different view controller, so i don't think that viewDidLoad of each one is a good solution.

I think to applicationDidFinishLaunching, but in this way will i make slow starup copying a sql database from bundle to Documents and writing a plist of 10 nodes?

Any seggestion is welcome, thank to everyone will read this.

Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1):

I think that applicationDidFinishLaunching is a good place to do it.  It will only need to copy the first time the user runs the app, right?

If you're worried about a slow initial start, and a view that needs these files copied is the first view to load then it won't help to defer copying until that view loads since this will essentially be at app startup anyway.

If, however, you don't need the data immediately and you find the copy to be slow, then you might consider doing the copy by spawning a thread to do the copy from applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidFinishLaunching` for any kind of fast preflight thing; like checking for a valid database, copy it there if it doesn't exist, wouldn't take more that a couple hundredths of a second. then you wont have to worry about it later.